# Как добавлять картинки в Django через сам сайт?

Tags: django, веб-программирование

Нужно добавлять картинки к посту через сам сайт(без админки).
В моём случае картинки не добавляются. Как это можно исправить?

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import View
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def posts_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context={'posts': posts})



def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)

if request.method == 'POST':
     comm_form = CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
     if comm_form.is_valid():
         comm_form = comm_form.save(commit=False)
         comm_form.post = post
         comm_form.save()
         return redirect(post)
     return render(request, 'main/post_detail.html', context={'comm_form': comm_form})
else:
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=pk)
    comm_form = CommentForm()

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'comm_form': comm_form,
        }
    return render(request, 'main/post_detail.html', context)
class PostCreate(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'main/post_create.html', context={'form': form})
    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_obj = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_obj)
        return render(request, 'main/post_create.html', context={'form': bound_form})
```

**urls.py(корневой файл)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    path('', include('main.urls'))
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название поста', max_length=150, db_index=True)
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name='Тело поста', blank=True, db_index=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', verbose_name='Категория', blank=True, related_name='posts')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Слаг', max_length=150, unique=True, blank=True)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, verbose_name='Изображение')
```

**post_create.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Post Create - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <form action="{% url 'post_create_url' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {% if field.errors %}
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    {{ field.errors }}
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        {{ field.label }}
                        <br>
                        {{ field }}
                        <br>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Создать пост</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавьте `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="{% url 'post_create_url' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

2. Добавьте `request.FILES`

```
class PostCreate(View):
    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```